# Multiple developer names for a single Google Developer account

Tags: android, google-play

Is it possible to have multiple developer names on a single Google Developer account? I want to have multiple apps with multiple teams without having to buy a new account for each.

Answer (score 2):

No, if you are publishing under the same account, the developer name will be the same. You can, however, [change the developer name](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/139626?hl=en). Changing the name applies to all the apps on the account though. If you already have another account, you can also [transfer the application](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/checklist/3294213). Point is, you'll need multiple accounts for multiple names.